# How to pass an integer array as argument in an item getter function?

Tags: python, csv

I want to pass an integer array into an itemgetter function. How can I do this?

Below is my code:

```
// Start of code

start ="1,3,5"
mylist = start.split(',')
key = itemgetter(*start)
or
key = itemgetter(mylist)
print key
```

Answer (score 4):

You have almost the right idea.  If you're trying to index an iterable, e.g. a list, then the items should be integers instead of strings:

```
>>> start = "1,3,5"
>>> mylist = [int(x) for x in start.split(',')]
>>> g = itemgetter(*mylist)
>>> g(range(10))
(1, 3, 5)
>>> g('abcdefghi')
('b', 'd', 'f')
```

Comment: im getting the following output                                                                                                                            <operator.itemgetter object at 0x0295D690>                                              for the following code :                                                                                                                                                                           start ="1,3,5"
mylist= [int(x) for x in start.split(',')]
print mylist
key = itemgetter(*mylist)
print key

Comment: i agree, but i have a string of integers as input and i want to convert that into an integer array and pass that array to itemgetter function